# How can add hint from settings in wpf material desgin

Tags: wpf

i use this:

```
 <PasswordBox Visibility="Visible" Name="premiumPasswordEs" Margin="20 0 0 0" Width="200"  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Contraseña" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

i want put in "materialDesgin:HintAssist.Hint" a text from the setting. How to?

Comment: With a binding, I'd assume; though I don't know what namespace `materialDesign` references.

Comment: This is a multilenguaje, how can change?

Comment: This is a whole other problem, and a new question. Search for "wpf localization".